# Module 'Facebook Blackberry sdk v0.8.25' not found

Tags: blackberry

I am new to blackberry application development, i want to integrate Facebook into my blackberry application. I downloaded Facebook blackberry SDK from this site http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/,  i added this jar file to my blackberry application,but while i run that application on blackberry 9930 simulator it shows "Error Starting XX: Module 'Facebook Blackberry SDK v0.8.25' not found"  any one please help me

Comment: is this still a problem?  the other question you posted yesterday suggests that maybe you got past this problem?  if it's no longer an issue, you could answer it yourself ... so people know that you don't need help with it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution, right click project, select Properties within this select java build path and tick mark both Facebook Blackberry SDK-v0.8.25 jar and Log4B-v9.4 and click OK button.

Now this problem solved